# Best way to Share data between all custom actions Install Shield

Tags: c#, installshield

We are using custom actions in Install Shield with c# and I want to share a data between multiple custom actions.

I already have an approach of writing it to text file from first custom action and for rest custom actions reading value from that file..
but I don't find it a good approach for following reasons.

1. IO operations are costly and they needed to be done for all custom actions.
2. Writing file can be permission issue for specific Operating Systems, since installer will execute on multiple Flavor of Windows OS, so any discrepency will create issue in Installer.

So, I am looking for best practice solution which can handle this scenario..

Looking forward for some great replies..

Answer (score 0):

We use 2 ways to do it
 - If we need share only text data and only during one installation process - we use Public Properties. The first CA sets properties, the other ones read this data. [MsiSetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370391(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MsiGetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370134(v=vs.85).aspx) will help you here, but don't forget about [Accessing or Setting Windows Installer Properties Through Deferred, Commit, and Rollback Custom Actions](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/AccessingProps-DeferredCAs.htm).
 - If need share data between different installation processes - we use Registry and System Search. The first installer writes data to some place in Registry - the other ones read it with help of System Search and set appropriate properties.

Comment: Igor,We need to get this property accessed by custom actions in c#, so that we could handle it in c#, with MSiSetProperty and MsiGetProperty, I think we need to send it through every custom action as parameter too, is it right??
Is there any better approach, I think registry and system search are also specific to machine privileges.

can you suggest something else?

Comment: 1. Properties which you set in first CA, will be available to read from next ones. Not sure if I understand, why you need to send them (properties to other CAs) if they are stored in the memory, and you can read these properties in any moment after they were set.
2. The second way is good only for sending data to another installers (if you have several, for example in chain MSI)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the theory is that immediate actions can determine exactly what later actions related to it will need to know, and thus can set properties or CustomActionData for those later actions as required. Properties can store any serialization format you can represent in a zero-terminated string. This is the one truly supported mechanism of Windows Installer for communicating between immediate actions, and especially to a deferred action.

However in practice this doesn't always work right. Sometimes reading the current state of the machine requires administrative privileges that are unavailable to the immediate action. Sometimes in order to run an effective rollback or commit action, you need to know what happened during the elevated attempt to make the changes. Even when gathering the information is possible without elevated privileges, it can be difficult to plan this all ahead of time, and it's tempting to trade off between ease and theoretical correctness.

It's not uncommon to instead share the name of a file through the property mechanism and update a shared file as you describe. The core difference is that the file name isn't predetermined; it's stored in %TEMP% or similar, and its name is communicated via properties. That resolves the elevation question, but not necessarily the security question.